# Node JS - Turn on/off logs based on type or levels

Tags: node.js, logging, log-level

Is there a way by which I can turn on/off certain logs, based on its type/levels.

For eg:
I have defined 3 levels: ALL, WARNING, CRITICAL

And I have my Log class, where I will set this. Say I set `Level: 'ALL'`
So this will log everything, wherever I have logged messages.

Now, when I set `Level: 'WARNING'`
This will only log messages, which are of warning type.

Can I do this with [Bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) ?
Or any other module?

Please help !!

Comment: https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#levels

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But while the app is running, and say if the log-file is filling very fast. And I decide, I want to log only `warn` and `fatal` logs.. So how do I do that?
Where do I change that from??

P.S. I know about log-rotation, but still.

Comment: You can use `logger.level('warn')` to log everything from `warn` "upwards" (that is, `warn`, `error` and `fatal` only).

Answer (score 1):

One work around would be to use Bunyan's DTrace facilities.Keep the log level higher and if you need to inspect low level log like debug you can run Dtrace command 
Examples
Trace all log messages coming from any Bunyan module on the system

> dtrace -x strsize=4k -qn 'bunyan*:::log-*{printf("%d: %s: %s", pid, probefunc, copyinstr(arg0))}'

Trace all log messages coming from the "wuzzle" component:

> dtrace -x strsize=4k -qn 'bunyan*:::log-*/strstr(this->str =
>   copyinstr(arg0), "\"component\":\"wuzzle\"") != NULL/{printf("%s",
>   this->str)}'

you need to manually install the "dtrace-provider" lib separately via npm install dtrace-provider
Check out the documentation [here](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan#runtime-log-snooping-via-dtrace)

Answer (score -1):

try using [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) module for logging .this is good for logging and has log rotation and other features